# Проблема с отображением windows form в Vusial Studio 2022

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

Нужно написать песочные часы на C++ в VS WinForms.
Создал файл формами руководствуясь [ссылке](https://programforyou.ru/poleznoe/how-to-create-windows-forms-cpp-project).
При запуске кода, появляется пустое белое окно и ничего не происходит/

```
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib")
#pragma once

namespace HourglassVer1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Сводка для MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        int midx, midy;
        int x1, x2, i, z;

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Panel^ panel1;
    protected:
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Timer^ timer1;
    private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^ components;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
            this->panel1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Panel());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->timer1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer(this->components));
            this->panel1->SuspendLayout();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            this->panel1->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::Info;
            this->panel1->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->panel1->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Top;
            this->panel1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
            this->panel1->Name = L"panel1";
            this->panel1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(681, 364);
            this->panel1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(280, 12);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"Старт";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->timer1->Interval = 1;
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ControlText;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(681, 421);
            this->Controls->Add(this->panel1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::MyForm_Load);
            this->panel1->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        if (button1->Text == "Старт") timer1->Enabled = true; else timer1->Enabled = false;
        if (button1->Text == "Стоп") button1->Text = "Старт"; else button1->Text = "Стоп";
    }
    private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        midx = this->ClientSize.Width / 2;
        midy = this->ClientSize.Height / 2;
        Graphics^ g = this->CreateGraphics();
        Bitmap^ bitmap = gcnew Bitmap(2 * midx, 2 * midy);
        Pen^ black = gcnew Pen(Color::Black);
        Pen^ green = gcnew Pen(Color::Lime, 1);
        Pen^ blue = gcnew Pen(Color::Blue);
        Pen^ yellow = gcnew Pen(Color::Yellow);

        for (i = -180; i < 181; i++) {
            if (abs(i) < 60) { x1 = -i; x2 = i; }
            else { x1 = -60; x2 = 60; }
            if (!abs(i) == 180) {
                g->DrawEllipse(green, (midx + x1), (midy + i), 1, 1);
                g->DrawEllipse(green, (midx + x2), (midy + i), 1, 1);
            }
            else {
                g->DrawLine(green, (midx + x1), (midy + i), (midx + x2), (midy + i));
            }
        }

        for (i = 1; i < 180; i++) {
            if (i < 60) { x1 = -i + 1; x2 = i - 1; }
            else { x1 = -59; x2 = 59; }
            if (i < 180) { g->DrawLine(yellow, (midx + x1), (midy - i), (midx + x2), (midy - i));
            g->DrawLine(blue, (midx + x1), (midy + i), (midx + x2), (midy + i));
            }
            else { g->DrawLine(blue, (midx + x1), (midy + i), (midx + x2), (midy + i)); }

            for (i = 179; i > 1; i--) {
                if (i < 60) {
                    x1 = -i + 1;
                    x2 = i - 1;
                }
                else {
                    x1 = -59;
                    x2 = 59;
                }
            }

        }
        g->DrawLine(blue, (midx + x1), (midy - i), (midx + x2), (midy - i));
        g->DrawLine(yellow, (midx + x1), (midy + i), (midx + x2), (midy + i));
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE)) exit(1);
        System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(10);

    }
    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    }
    };
}
```